# Pandas: If substring is in string, return value of adjacent cell

Tags: python, excel, loops, csv, pandas

I currently have the following working code:

```
for i,gram in enumerate(df['Unigram']):
    for j,word in enumerate(df1['Keyword']):
      if df.ix[i,'Unigram'] in df1.loc[j,'Keyword']:
        df.ix[i,'Cost'] += df1.ix[j,'Cost']
```

But it takes a good while for large data sets. Is there a more efficient method of going about this? I've heard that Pandas DataFrames prefer not to be looped, but am not sure of the best approach. A working solution would be able to account for multiple matches.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are `df['Unigram']` and `df1['Keyword']` Series objects? Then you should replace your `enumerate()` calls with `iteritems()`. Example: instead of `enumerate(df['Unigram'])` use `df['Unigram'].iteritems()`. If they are DataFrame objects, you can use iterrows().

Comment: They're columns in their respective DataFrames... does that make them Series objects?

Comment: Yes, if they are columns in a DataFrame object, they are handled as Series objects. You can test it with `print type(df['Unigram'])`. The output should be something like `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`.

Comment: In the problem code, a column ('Cost') is being updated in the row being iterated over.  You should not change an item being iterated by `iteritems()` or `iterrows()`, because they may return a copy of the data.  So changing the iterated item may not change the underlying data.  [Docs -See the pink warning box](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#iteration)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `str.contains()`:

```
for i,gram in enumerate(df['Unigram']):
    select = df1['Keyword'].str.contains(gram, na=False)
    df.ix[i,'Cost'] += df1[select]['Cost']
```

Comment: I'm getting `Incompatible indexer with Series` errors -- any ideas?

Comment: This one: `df.ix[i,'Cost'] += df1[select]['Cost']`